# Dynamic model query for orderBy()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, lambda

Is there an equivalent for the following?

```
  // convert model to dynamic (this is how the model is coming in)
  IEnumerable<dynamic> dynmodel = (IEnumerable < dynamic >)Model;

  // dynamic lambda ???
  string col = "x.Name";
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: dynmodel.OrderBy(x => @col)); // Doesn't resolve but need an equivalent here!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a project out there called Dynamic LINQ.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx